# Styled component ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

```js
export const RedHeader = styled.div`
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: gray;
`;

function Header(className) {
    return (
        <RedHeader className={className}>
            this is styled component example
            <p>test</p>
        </RedHeader>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

I have red the cdocumentation but i can't figure out, why should we use `className` as a props and after that in `className={className}`?

Answer (score 0):

When using styled components, there should be no need to use `className` (which renders as `class` attribute in HTML) anymore. In your example, you pass `className` to the styled component, but the styled component does not use it in any way.

You can pass properties to your styled components if you want dynamic styling like you would do with class names in classic CSS.

Example with style that depends on a class name:

```
 const RedHeader = styled.div`
  color: red;
  &.active {
    color: blue;
  }
 `
```

Example with props:

```
 const RedHeader = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.active ? 'blue' : 'red'}
 `

 function Header({ active }) {
    return (
        <RedHeader active={active}>
            example
        </RedHeader>
      )
  }
```